# Is it possible to use multiple constructor functions to create 1 new instance?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Is there a straightforward way to use 2 or more [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) functions to create 1 new instance?

For example,

```
function Vehicle(manufacturer, cost) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.cost = cost;
}

function Aircraft(crewSize, range) {
    this.crewSize = crewSize;
    this.range = range;
}

let p51Mustang = new Vehicle + Aircraft ???
```

I know that it's possible to use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to chain constructors together like this,

```
function Vehicle(manufacturer, cost) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.cost = cost;
}

function Aircraft(manufacturer, cost, crewSize, range) {
    Vehicle.call(this, manufacturer, cost)
    this.crewSize = crewSize;
    this.range = range;
}

let p51Mustang = new Aircraft('North American', '$50,000', 1, '2,656 Km');
```

But is there a way to do this by calling both constructors at the same time and not chaining them together?  Thanks so much for any input!

Comment: Could you explain your desired output? An object can only inherit from one prototype object.

Comment: My output would be something like my 'chained' together example.  2, constructor functions, 4 parameters, 1 new instance.  I'm just using this for testing.  I'm trying to understand how far I can push constructors before I hit the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`.

```js
function Vehicle(manufacturer, cost) {
  return {
    manufacturer,
    cost
  }

}

function Aircraft(crewSize, range) {
  return {
    crewSize,
    range
  }
}

let p51Mustang = Object.assign(Vehicle("North American", '$50,000'), Aircraft(1, '2,656 Km'));
console.log(p51Mustang);
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was possible to build a new object with return {}.  That's really interesting.  Is there an advantage to doing it this way instead of using this and new?

Comment: @DR01D the advantage is that it's more clear and, to me at least, I feel like it's more composable. The difference is that with new you're creating an instance of a type of object, which is more expensive, but it allows you to adjust the prototype at any time.  So if you wanted to add a method to all instances of the Vehicle type later in your code, you could by setting Vehicle.prototype.methodName, etc. However in your current use case, you're disconnecting from your prototypes by combining constructors into a new object anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Here a snippet:

```js
function Vehicle(manufacturer, cost) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    this.cost = cost;
}

function Aircraft(crewSize, range) {
    this.crewSize = crewSize;
    this.range = range;
}


let p51Mustang = Object.assign( new Vehicle('BMW', 1000), new Aircraft(10, 200))

console.log(obj)
```